# My PHP cURL Script Is Returning 'Couldn't resolve host'

Tags: php, curl

First off, I've read other similar problems and have spoken with my host to confirm cURL is running and configured properly on my server, which it is.

I'm new to cURL so I'm not very confident in my script and I'm guessing the problem is there. I have api access to a service to check the status of and place orders. This script is meant to check the status of orders.

```
function get_CSA_order_status($pid){
// Get cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(api_token => 'my api token', order_id => '54512'));                      

// Send the request & save response to $results
$results = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($ch);
//return array and dump results
var_dump($results);

}
```

**Script Output**

```
Array
6
Couldn’t resolve host ‘Array’
bool(false)
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to gofr1 I was able to resolve my issue which was passing the URL through an array. I have edited the code above to reflect my current script, but now for some reason it's not accepting the order id.

**Current Output**

```
string(89) “{“code”:400,”payload”:{“messages”:{“order_id”:[“The order_id you provided is invalid”]}}}”
```

I've changed the url and removed my api key. If anything looks incorrect please let me know.

**SOLVED!**

Everything is working thank you to everyone who helped and suggested solutions.

Comment: Check the domain is host is available by putting the url in browser. Possibly there is a http to https redirect not being followed so try adding. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: @TimAckroyd Hi Tim, I made the FOLLOWLOCATION change as you suggested but nothing changed. I also visited the URL in my browser and added the output to my question. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but just to let you know my site is https and the target URL is http.

Comment: @nickyb your script looks correct, what errors you get when running this? I see only response from your browser.

Comment: @gofr1 I've edited my question to include the output.

Comment: Have you tried using GET instead of POST?

Comment: @DarinPeterson The API only accepts POST requests.

Comment: Try building an HTML form using a post with the action pointing to the URL in question, and the two variables you've shown in your code as hidden variables with the name as key and value as your value. Include a submit button, click it and see what kind of response you get.

Comment: Try this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com');`

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, array('http://domain.com'));` is incorrect.  The URL is a string, not an array.  This is why it is saying it could not resolve host `Array`.  The array is getting converted to a string which in PHP always just returns `Array`.

Comment: @gofr1 Hey good call on removing the array that did it. Now I'm just trying to figure out why the request is not accepting api_token and order_id `string(86) “{“code”:400,”payload”:{“messages”:{“api_token”:[“The api token field is required.”]}}}”`

Comment: replace 

   ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(api_token => 'my api token')); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( order_id => '54512'));```

with

    ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('api_token' => 'my api token', 'order_id' => '54512'));```

Comment: @honerlawd Thanks, I made the change as you suggested and it's accepting my, but not the order id. I know for certain the order id is valid and i have tried more than one. `string(89) “{“code”:400,”payload”:{“messages”:{“order_id”:[“The order_id you provided is invalid”]}}}”`

Comment: @nickyb please post tour current script